# Invariant Violation & Render Error on Simple React Native App

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

new to React Native so apologies if this is a newbie question. I am using Expo, and my app works on web but when I use iOS through Expo I am getting 18 errors of two categories. Either an `Invariant Violation` which will be detailed below, an `Render Error`.

****Error class 1****

```
Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `input` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

This error is located at:
    in input
    in Unknown
    in span
    in Unknown
    in div (created by FormGroup)
    in FormGroup (created by App)
    in form (created by Form)
    in Form (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in DevAppContainer (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

****Error class 2****

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

This error is located at:
    in div
    in div
    in span
    in Unknown
    in div (created by FormGroup)
    in FormGroup (created by App)
    in form (created by Form)
    in Form (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in DevAppContainer (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

Here is my code, thanks in advance!

```
import React from 'react';

import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import config from './src/aws-exports';

import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import RangeSlider from 'react-bootstrap-range-slider';

Amplify.configure(config)

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mood: 1,
      sleep: 3,
      energy: 3,
      clarity: 5,
      social: 2,
      notes: ""
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    console.log("submitted state:", this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group>
            <Text>Mood</Text>
              <RangeSlider
                value={this.state.mood}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({mood: e.target.value})}
                min={1}
                max={5}/>
            <Text>Sleep</Text>
              <RangeSlider
                value={this.state.sleep}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({sleep: e.target.value})}
                min={1}
                max={5}/>
            <Text>Energy</Text>
              <RangeSlider
                value={this.state.energy}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({energy: e.target.value})}
                min={1}
                max={5}/>
            <Text>Clarity</Text>
              <RangeSlider
                value={this.state.clarity}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({clarity: e.target.value})}
                min={1}
                max={5}/>
            <Text>Social</Text>
              <RangeSlider
                value={this.state.social}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({social: e.target.value})}
                min={1}
                max={5}/>
            <Text>Check-in Notes</Text>
              <Form.Control 
                as="textarea"
                rows={3}
                value={this.state.notes}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({notes: e.target.value})}/>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
        <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you are using `import { Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';`. That might be not react native compatible?

Maybe try out something like [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/) instead?